du fails to show size of home directory
du -sh $HOME

gets stuck when running. This is the last few lines of output:
du: cannot access '/home/user/.local/share/waydroid/data/media/0/DCIM/Camera': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/home/user/.local/share/waydroid/data/gsi/dsu': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/home/user/.local/share/waydroid/data/gsi/ota': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/home/user/.local/share/waydroid/data/gsi/remount': Permission denied


Have you used some software called “waydroid” as root (via sudo)?

@Kusalananda I had a mounted file system in my home directory

@Kusalananda waydroid was installed using dnf from the fedora updates repo

du eventually finished but it too a long time. I remember that my home directory has a mounted file system which is very large. That must be why du took so long, it must have been scanning that mounted directory.
However, I don't know why du didn't produce any additional output after the one I posted in my question.
Update:
du did show the size of the arguments but I missed it because I pressed random buttons since it was taking too long, and so du's output was mixed in with typed-in letters like so: jk21G.

Hang on, if there was no output, that's a different issue. The fact that it was slow is expected when having it traverse a whole separate file system. But it should still return the size. So is the question now answered?

@terdon there was no additional output because there were no more errors. du only encounters errors with the directories in my question. Yes question is answered.

The question does not appear to be answered.  du always reports the calculated size of its arguments.  The fact that there were no additional output apart from the errors that you reported means something is still wrong.

The information in this "answer" should have been included in the body of the question.

@Kusalananda I've updated my answer. Let me know if anything else is needed.
